# How can I use Z3 to simplify an linear inequality ？

Tags: z3

How can I use Z3 to simplify an linear inequality ?
The inequality is as follows：

```
(x+k−1<n)∧(z>x+k−1)∧(x+k<n)∧(z<=x+k)
```

and the ideal result should be as following.

```
z-x<=k < z−x+1
```

But how to solve it using z3?

Comment: Users on SO are more inclined to help with questions where the asker demonstrates that they invested work themselves already. I.e. describe what you've tried already, how far you got, what your current understanding of the situation is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Z3 can perform some simplifications indeed, but expecting it to do well on symbolic computation would be too much to ask for. Since your question has no details, it's impossible to give you any guidance. If your interest is symbolic mathematics, perhaps using a symbolic-algebra tool is the better choice. For instance, Wolfram Alpha can handle your example quite well: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%2Bk%E2%88%921%3Cn)%E2%88%A7(z%3Ex%2Bk%E2%88%921)%E2%88%A7(x%2Bk%3Cn)%E2%88%A7(z%3C%3Dx%2Bk)